# For what 0 between comma and bracket is used for?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const sumOfCubes = array => {
    return array.reduce(function(sum,value){
        return sum + Math.pow(value, 3);
    },0) // this line
}

console.log(sumOfCubes([1, 5, 9]));
```

Hello, i have a question. I needed to create a function that takes in an array of numbers and returns the sum of its cubes. I used it.

Comment: It is the initial value for the accumulator of the reduce function

Comment: The 0 is the initial value of `sum`.  It's documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: It's `array.reduce(function (...) { ... }, 0)`… The `0` is the second argument to `reduce`.

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation of the `reduce` method? Isn't that the first place you should look when you don't understand what a function argument is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the reduce function is the initial value, so for the sum it starts at 0. That's why the `,0)` is there for.